# TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError - how should we handle this on the front-end

Tags: transactions, web3.js, slots

I am getting an error message when creating a signature

```
Error: 

TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 2XqzFuyv5YWpDPTT87CVu48QJPemGSu5rbCazrNBgY6D3mS8rugKugtzXDGpN6XZF8FPyWwXQvzfm4ZyMx6gTf6j has expired: block height exceeded.
```

Signature created like this:

```
const transaction = transaction.add(...)

  transaction.feePayer = publicKey;
          transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
          const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()

// ----> Phantom recommended way of signing tx
          const { signature }  = await provider.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);

 const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(
            {
              blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
              lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
              signature,
            }
          );
```

After few seconds/minute or 2 I get the above error message although the TX is confirmed and finalized.

How to handle this? Why is the error popping up if the tx gets added to the block?

Comment: This error comes from `connection.confirmTransaction`, not from creating the signature.

Comment: I expect that if you used `connection.confirmTransaction(signature)` you would not get this error, though this approach is apparently deprecated now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s already being tracked in GitHub issues as a bug: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/25955

Comment: Let's close this one then. But it's good that thread is here on stack overflow so that people can follow from stack -> github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that you can follow along with here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/25955

Comment: Will vote to close this Stack Exchange question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/25955).  I'd suggest you make your experience known in the Github issue